# How to get list distinct in spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I get a list of this entity:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "selected_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "selected_start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "selected_end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "voter_unique_name" , referencedColumnName = "unqiue_name")
    private Voter voterUniqueName;
```

I want to explain my problem with an example hoping I can explain it well.
If we have a meeting with a time from 17:00-18:00 o clock on 01.08.2021. Multiple participants can click and save themselves for this time. This is alright and what I want to achieve but now I want to get for example all participants who selected the time and date above, this kinda works but with the problem:

[image: view of application]

The times pill of 17:00-18:00 are shown two times this is due to my Database looking like this right now:

[image: Db image]
Because there are different voter_unique_name it gets it multiple times. I tried working with this code:

```
List<VoterAvailableTime> findDistinctByMeetingNameAndDateAndStartTimeAndEndTime(String meetingName, String date, String startTime, String endTime);
```

Using distinct but it still gets multiple times there. How can I make it so my times will be shown not multiple but single time?

update:

controller:

```
@GetMapping("/filterby")
    public List<VoterAvailableTimeDTO> findByDateMeetingStartAndEndTime(@RequestParam(value = "meetingName") String meetingName,
                                                                        @RequestParam(value = "date") String date, @RequestParam(value = "startTime") String startTime,
                                                                        @RequestParam(value = "endTime") String endTime) {
        return voterAvailableTimeService.findByMeetingNameAndDateAndStartAndEndTime(meetingName, date, startTime, endTime);
    }
```

service:

```
 public List<VoterAvailableTimeDTO> findByDateAndMeetingName(String meetingName, String date){
 List<VoterAvailableTimeI> voterAvailableTimesList =  voterAvailableTimeRepository.findByVoterAvailableTimeByMeetingNameAndDate(meetingName, date);
 return voterAvailableTimesList.stream()
         .map(this::convertToDto2)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

}

converter:

```
  private VoterAvailableTimeDTO convertToDto2(VoterAvailableTimeI voterAvailableTime) {
        VoterAvailableTimeDTO voterAvailableTimeDTO = new VoterAvailableTimeDTO();
        voterAvailableTimeDTO.setDate(voterAvailableTime.getDate());
        voterAvailableTimeDTO.setStartTime(voterAvailableTime.getStartTime());
        voterAvailableTimeDTO.setEndTime(voterAvailableTime.getEndTime());
        voterAvailableTimeDTO.setMeetingName(voterAvailableTime.getMeetingName());

        return voterAvailableTimeDTO;
    }
```

repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.meetingName, t.date FROM VoterAvailableTime t " +
                "WHERE t.meetingName = ?1 and t.date = ?2")
        List<VoterAvailableTimeI> findByVoterAvailableTimeByMeetingNameAndDate(String meetingName, String date);
```

Comment: Why is all this date repeated in the database? Why is there not a single row with `id`, `date`, `start`, `end`, and then a join-column to join the voters to this meeting time? What is the overall purpopse of this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you see is correct because **`Distinct`** works for all fields **in [Spring Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)**.

If you want to do it according to `date`, `startTime`, `endTime` and `meetingName` fields, you need to write a special query with using [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

The result of the query is different from the whole object. so you need to use **[Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)**:

```java
public interface VoterAvailableTimeI {
    String getMeetingName();
    String getDate();
    String getStartTime();
    String getEndTime();
}
```

Now we write our query that makes distinct according to `date`, `startTime`, `endTime` and `meetingName` fields and then connect it to **our projection interface (`VoterAvailableTimeI`):**

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT t.meetingName as meetingName, t.date as date, t.startTime as startTime, t.endTime as endTime FROM VoterAvailableTime t " +
            "WHERE t.meetingName = ?1 and t.date = ?2 and t.startTime = ?3 and t.endTime = ?4")
List<VoterAvailableTimeI> findDistinctByMeetingNameAndDateAndStartTimeAndEndTime(String meetingName, String date, String startTime, String endTime);
```

Comment: So two questions I am calling this method from my service and controller return a VoterAvailableTimeDTO do i have to change these to the interface as well?

Comment: I updated my question so you would understand me better @iswailyildiz I added my service and controller

Comment: There is no problem in `Controller` and `Service` layer. Replace your `Repository` with the one I posted. Don't forget to add the `VoterAvailableTimeI` interface and update your `convertToDto` method accordingly. *(There may be other solutions as well.)*

Comment: My convertToDTO has to use my new Interface instead of the entity am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! @haso

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions but I have two more questions. You have left out the voterUniqueName out from the interface was this an error or intentionally done if yes why did you do it? And another question is you have put numbers in the queries what do the numbers do?

Comment: 1. If you add `voterUniqueName`, these 2 records will be different from each other. 2. This is the method of passing parameters to the query, there are different methods. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters

Comment: Hey thanks, I updated my service, repository and converter but I am getting a null back, one chip is shown with null- null inside. I updated my question could you take a look? I previously had posted the wrong service method now I did the correct one with your answer in mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235760/discussion-between-iswailyildiz-and-haso).

Answer (score 0):

Query Result is correct that is how distinct works it checked all columns to give the results

- **You can try adding GROUP BY statement as following**

```
@Query("select distinct m "
    + "from meetings m where meeting_name=:meetingName and selected_date=:selectedDate and   " 
    + "selected_start_time=:selectedStartDate "
    + "and selected_end_time=:selectedEndDate "
    + "group by meeting_name")
List<VoterAvailableTime> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("meetingName") String meetingName, @Param("selectedDate") String
    selectedDate,@Param("selectedStartDate") String  selectedStartDate,@Param("selectedEndDate") String  selectedEndDate);
```

- **Or Else you can specified columns which needs to be distinct as follows**
  For this you need to add `interface` which exists meeting_name, selected_date, selected_start_time, selected_end_time variables for example interface called `VoterAvailableTimeSlots`.
  We need to do it since resulting number of parameters differs with Entity class. That's why we need to use **projection interface**.

```
@Query("select distinct meeting_name,selected_date,selected_start_time,selected_end_time "
    + "from meetings m where meeting_name=:meetingName and selected_date=:selectedDate and   " 
    + "selected_start_time=:selectedStartDate "
    + "and selected_end_time=:selectedEndDate "
    + "group by meeting_name")
List<VoterAvailableTimeSlots> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("meetingName") String meetingName, @Param("selectedDate") String
    selectedDate,@Param("selectedStartDate") String  selectedStartDate,@Param("selectedEndDate") String  selectedEndDate);
```

Comment: Your 1st example won't work if you don't mark `nativeQuery=true`, 2nd example is throw a `ConverterNotFoundException` because 4 fields and pattern are not working.

Comment: @iswailyildiz Oh my bad, for that we need to use Projections since it gives different parameters than VoterAvailableTime Entity.

Comment: @iswailyildiz when we are using `@Query` annotation **by default, the query definition uses JPQL**. So we don't need to add `nativeQuery=true`

Comment: Hi, sorry for not replying yesterday was a bit hectic and stressfull for me. So should I try to use the first example I am kind of confused right now? is there no way to do this with the jparepository class?

Comment: @haso if you follow the answer I wrote, the result will be as you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694491/2039546

Comment: @haso you can try with first solution I mean by adding group statement as I mentioned above, if you need any help let me know.